# Не работает BroadcastReceiver зарегистрированый через манифест (AlarmManager)

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-alarm-manager, android-broadcastreceiver

Всем доброго времени суток) Broadcast ресивер зарегистрированый через сам манифест не работает. Раньше регистрировал их програмно и проблем не было. Теперь же появилась необходимость чтобы ресивер работал и при незапущеном приложении, но с этим уже возникли трудности. Ресивер никак не хочет отлавливать кастомные интенты и никаким образом на них не реагирует. Заранее спасибо за помощь! Код ниже:)

```
<receiver
            android:name="packagename.ExecuteTaskReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">

            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="my_custom_ection"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Клас ресивера

```
public class ExecuteTaskReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"SSSSSSS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra(AppKeys.TASK_TITLE))
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context,
                        0,
                        i,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                );

        Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(uri);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(12345, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

AlarmManager set

```
Context context = mTaskView.getContext();
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppKeys.TASK_DONE);
        intent.setClass(context, ExecuteTaskReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppKeys.TASK_TITLE, mTask.getTitle());
        mTaskView.getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getTaskTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: <action android:name="my_custom_ection"></action>
и
Intent intent = new Intent(AppKeys.TASK_DONE);
у них точно совпадает actionName ?

Comment: @Vitaly Tomashevsky совпадает 100%